# How to use function to copy one object's input into the other

Tags: c++, object

```
  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
    private :
    char str[848];

    public :

    MyClass()
    {

    }


    MyClass(char a[])  
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 848 ; i ++)
        {
            str[i] = a[i];
        }

    }

    MyClass operator () (char a[])
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i <sizeof(str) ; i++)
        {
            str[i] = a[i];
        }

    }

    void myFunction (MyClass m)
    {
        MyClass d;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(str) ; i++)
        {

        m.str[i] = d.str[i];
        }



    }

    void display()
    {
        cout << str;
    }
};

int main()
{   
    MyClass m1;  

    MyClass m2("COVID-19") , m3("Mid2020");

    m2.display(); // Displays Covid 19

    m2.myFunction(m3);

    m2.display(); // Displays Mid2020


}
```

So here It displays COVID19 two times, but I want the other input(MID 2020) to display
I can't make the `myFunction` properly, I tried copying it but it didn't work
ALSO, I cannot use strcpy here, because I'm restricted not to use it in any circumstances
So far my code is above, any help will be appreciated

Comment: What do you think `MyClass d` inside `myFunction` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
private:
    char str[848];

public:

    MyClass()
    {

    }


    MyClass(const char* a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 848; i++)
        {
            str[i] = a[i];
        }

    }

    MyClass operator () (char a[])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(str); i++)
        {
            str[i] = a[i];
        }

    }

    void myFunction(const MyClass& m)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(str); i++)
        {

            str[i] = m.str[i];
        }

    }

    void display()
    {
        cout << str;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass m1;

    MyClass m2("COVID-19"), m3("Mid2020");

    m2.display(); // Displays Covid 19

    m2.myFunction(m3);

    m2.display(); // Displays Mid2020


}
```

result:

```
COVID-19Mid2020
```

First of all, copy constructor should work with `const char*` instead of char[] because that is the type of "COVID-19" and "Mid2020". 
Then you do `m2.myFucntion(m3);`. Actually there is no need to create a new object in myFunction definition. If it is not a static function-member myFunction get *this pointer. *this will point to m2 in `m2.myFunction(m3);`. So you can do `str[i] = m.str[i];` instead of creating a new object.

Comment: Please describe your answer